# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'handleShow' of 'object null' as it is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've searched about this issue here and in other forums but the solutions to this I found were very specific to the question at hand.

I have two small functions who both control the visibility of a React Bootstrap modal, and help pass some parameters to it.

Here are the two functions:

```
modalVisibility = ({ handleShow }) => {
  this.showModal = handleShow;
};

openArticle = data => {
  console.log(data.title);
  this.setState(
    {
      title: data.title,
      content: data.fullArticle        },
    () => {
      this.showModal();
    }
  );
};
```

Here's the modal component they're triggering:

```
<Modal ref={this.modalVisibility} title={this.state.title} article={this.state.content}></Modal>
```

And the button trigger:

```
<button onClick={() => this.modalVisibility(data)}>
```

All of the above works (mostly) fine.

The issue comes when I want to get out of this component and go to another one via the navbar menu (using react-router-dom). Whenever I switch to another page the above error appears:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'handleShow' of 'object null' as it is null

and doesn't leave until I refresh the page. Then it appears again after I go back to the page hosting the Modal and switching back to any other again.

Comment: `modalVisibility` it is confusing its a method to call or a `ref` to make a reference to the element.

Comment: It's supposed to be a ref for the modal to show/hide when required.

Comment: can you try by adding different ref to the modal?

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara tried, no changes.

Comment: Rewrite modalVisibility function to `modalVisibility = (obj) => { this.showModal = obj.handleShow }` so you can put a breakpoint and check why modalVisibility it being called.

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara You were spot on. Mind posting it as an answer so I can verify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite modalVisibility function to below so you can put a breakpoint and check why modalVisibility it being called.

```
modalVisibility = (obj) => { 
   this.showModal = obj && obj.handleShow 
}
```